# I dropped my camera and am experiencing delays

Tags: canon

So I just got a new Canon Rebel T6, but I dropped it. Almost threw it to be more precise. In short, I have arachnophobia really  bad, there was a huge spider on my camera when I picked it up, I threw my camera away from me and ran. When I picked it up nothing seemed to be damaged, it turned on, but when I went to take a picture, the beep that comes after the click was slowed down to half a beat, and my picture came out blurry. So I read through the manual, and switched the dial on top of my camera to a setting that sets the camera to default, and it works fine on that, but now I can't use close-up or sports or any other settings on my camera, and the default setting always has the flash on. Any advice?
UPDATE: I went through all the different modes on my camera, and I found that it lags on Night Portrait, Sports, Culinary, P, Flash Off, and Landscape. I did try factory settings twice, and it didn't work. I honestly am at a lost right now.

Comment: 1. Don't throw or drop your camera in the future. 2. What settings did you select? What are you doing to try to select the other settings?

Comment: There's no setting on the mode dial that says, "default." What setting is the dial set to when it works? How bright is the light when you are trying to take a picture? Indoors? Outdoors in full sunlight?

Comment: You likely got the camera in 'Tv" mode with a slow speed. Does the camera work in "P" mode?

Comment: @MichaelClark I turned the dial to Scene Intelligent Auto. I would say pretty bright because the flash is always on when I have it on this setting. I'm not exactly sure. I just got this camera so I'm still learning all the different modes.

Comment: @xenoid No it does not work in "P" mode. I've noticed that whenever the flash is on, like in Scene Intelligence or Portrait, that it works, but with other modes, the beep is slow and my picture comes out blurry.

Comment: With a flash the scene luminosity is mostly set by the flash and the flsh is short, do you don't get motions blur. It seems your camera is stuck is some mode with slow aperture. Two things to check: reset to to factory settings (somewhere in the "C.fn" menus IIRC) and if this is not enought, remove the battery for a couple of days. Is this doesn't fix the problem, then its likely a hardware issue. I don't know how you paid the camera, but sometimes credit cards carry an insurance on the goods purchased with it.

Comment: How bright is the *ambient* light when you are trying to take a picture? (That is, the light *without* the flash.) If the light is very dim and you are using a relatively slow kit lens, the camera will use a longer shutter time in order to expose the scene properly when you are not in an exposure mode that automatically turns on the flash.

Answer (score 1):

Did any button get visibly moshed in? That tends to get them stuck in a pressed-down state, which is really good at confusing electronics.

Also, fire the camera without a lens, on a slow speed, and observe whether the mirror seems to be working as expected.

Also, check if any kind of self timer or multiframe NR/HDR/bracketing mode got accidentally activated.

Also, if you haven't done so yet, try using another lens - a partially jammed lens could delay exposure in multiple ways.